# Different results of XMLLint and Xerces on XSD Schema validation?

Tags: xml, command-line, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation

Context: I'm trying to find a way to validate XSD and XML against XSD that is automatable for integration into a software build-process. The input is files, and for the output an exit code or reliably regex’able console output would be sufficient. I am operating in a Windows environment.

As XML and XSD input I have taken an example from Wikipedia (article "XML Schema (W3C)").

As tools I have chosen to try [XMLLint](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/) and [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/stdinparse-3.html).

The issue is, XMLLint and Xerces give different results.

Which leads me to my questions: What other options to evaluate the tools, do I have? How am I supposed to decide which tool to choose?

XML data example from Wikipedia, SimpleAddress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SimpleAddress.xsd">
  <Recipient>Mr. Walter C. Brown</Recipient>
  <House>49</House>
  <Street>Featherstone Street</Street>
  <Town>LONDON</Town>
  <PostCode>EC1Y 8SY</PostCode>
  <Country>UK</Country>
</Address>
```

XSD schema example from Wikipedia, SimpleAddress.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Recipient" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="House" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Town" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="County" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="PostCode" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Country" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="IN" />
              <xs:enumeration value="DE" />
              <xs:enumeration value="ES" />
              <xs:enumeration value="UK" />
              <xs:enumeration value="US" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

First my tests with XMLLint:

```
$ xmllint.exe --noout --schema SimpleAddress.xsd SimpleAddress.xml
SimpleAddress.xml validates

$ xmllint.exe --noout --schema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd SimpleAddress.xsd
SimpleAddress.xsd validates
```

XMLLint gives me also meaningful error results when I intentionally put an extra attribute or tag in the file to be validated.

With XMLLint, I also tried to validate the W3C’s XML Schema Definition against itself:

```
$ xmllint.exe --noout --schema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd validates
```

Second my tests with Xerces, that yields a lot of warnings and errors:

```
$ StdInParse.exe -n -s -f -v=always < SimpleAddress.xml
stdin: 1 ms (7 elems, 2 attrs, 19 spaces, 56 chars)

$ StdInParse.exe -n -s -f -v=always < SimpleAddress.xsd
Error at (file stdin, line 2, char 87): no declaration found for element 'xs:schema'
Error at (file stdin, line 2, char 87): attribute 'elementFormDefault' is not declared for element     'xs:schema'
Error at (file stdin, line 2, char 87): attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/}xs' is not declared  for element 'xs:schema'
Error at (file stdin, line 3, char 30): no declaration found for element 'xs:element'
(…)
```

For the following tests I have added the “xmlns:xsi” and “xsi:schemaLocation” attributes to the opening tag of SimpleAddress.xsd:

```
<xs:schema 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"
>
```

XMLLint yields the same result:

```
$ xmllint.exe --noout --schema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd SimpleAddress.xsd
SimpleAddress.xsd validates
```

Xerces yields even more warnings and errors, now concerning the W3C’s documents too:

```
$ StdInParse.exe -n -s -f -v=always < SimpleAddress.xsd
Warning at (file http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd, line 99, char 7): attribute 'id' has already been declared for element 'xs:simpleType'
Warning at (file http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd, line 122, char 7): attribute 'id' has already been declared for element 'xs:list'
Warning at (file http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd, line 130, char 7): attribute 'id' has already been declared for element 'xs:union'
Warning at (file http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd, line 140, char 20): attribute 'id' has already been declared for element 'xs:maxExclusive'
(…)
Error at (file stdin, line 15, char 68): unable to find validator for simple type of attribute 'maxOccurs'
Error at (file stdin, line 16, char 56): unable to find validator for simple type of attribute 'maxOccurs'
Error at (file stdin, line 17, char 50): unable to find validator for simple type of attribute 'maxOccurs'
```

In conclusion XMLLint seems to do what I need, however it has one major drawback. It requires me to specify the XSD file to validate against as a separate argument, as it seems to be unable to read the according xmlns attribute from the XML input files.

On the other hand there’s Xerces. It seems to be widely used and claims to be faithful to the very same standards used in these kind of documents, but yields a lot of errors and warnings even about the W3C’s documents. So, I’m asking myself, if I’m using it right? I would like to get it to work as it wouldn’t require me to find a workaround for XMLLint’s necessary extra argument.

Comment: note the number of followers for each of your tags. There are much more popular tags that would be valid for this question, xml being one, and likely xmllint or xmlstarlet (if you're will to switch tools). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'm new to StackOverflow. Thank you very much for that hint! I have added the tags, however it didn't change anything with regard to an answer. :( -- I'm willing to change tools in general, yet I'm still wondering why two so very praised tools have such different results.

Answer (score 0):

You should not validate an XMLSchema against the W3C Schema (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd). Instead, validate an 'empty' XML document (only a root) against your XMLSchema to see if your XMLSchema contains any errors.

Comment: It is good that when one validates XML against XSD that that XSD gets a validtion too. However, I couldn't find any source stating that clearly. Also, XSD is XML too, thus it should be possible to validate the XSD Schema against itself? And I haven't foud any source either that says the specification gets some special treatment. That would inconcsistent in my eyes.